# Password with @ can't connect the database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odbc

When I tried to connect database from Python, my password contains special character say for example: ***123@789***. My Connection fails because of this.

I make connection to the database as follows:

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sybase+pyodbc://user:123@789@Database')
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback of your error?

Comment: Can you change the password so it doesn't have `@` in it?

Comment: Hey @JohnGordon just curious, But does that @ / special character really matter? Do you think that would cause a problem ?

Comment: Changing your password just to conform to a specific interface is the wrong approach. You *can* specify whatever password you have if you use the interface properly.

Comment: Try escaping the @ symbol with `\\`.

Comment: @MaheshKumaran `@` is used to separate the password from the username in the connect string, so yes it is a problem.

Answer (score 8):

URL-encode the `@` in the password. Adapted from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html,

```
import urllib.parse
password = urllib.parse.quote_plus("123@789")  # '123%40456'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'sybase+pyodbc://user:{password}@Database')
```

Alternatively, let `sqlalchemy` generate the URL for you using `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL`.